# Connect with RJDBC like with odbc

Tags: r, sql-server, jdbc

I am trying to connect to my MS SQL database with RJDBC and I don't know what to fill in `url` argument. With odbc this was enough:

```
dbConnect(odbc::odbc(),
          Driver = "SQL Server",
          dsn = "MyDsn",
          uid = "User",
          pwd = "123456",
          server = "myserver123456\\myserver1",
          database = "MyDatabase")
```

When I swap the driver from odbc to jdbc then it fails:

```
dbConnect(RJDBC::JDBC(classPath = "C:/jdbc/mssql-jdbc-7.0.0.jre8.jar"),
          Driver = "SQL Server",
          dsn = "MyDsn",
          uid = "User",
          pwd = "123456",
          server = "myserver123456\\myserver1",
          database = "MyDatabase")
```

error: `Error in .jcall("java/sql/DriverManager", "Ljava/sql/Connection;", "getConnection",  : 
  argument "url" is missing, with no default`

What should i write in url argument? How to get know?

Answer (score 1):

RJDBC uses different arguments for the `dbConnect` function: a driver definition and a connection URL (the piece you are missing). For example (from https://www.rforge.net/RJDBC/), to connect to a MySQL Database, your code would look like the following:

> ```
> library(RJDBC)
> drv <- JDBC("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver",
>        "/etc/jdbc/mysql-connector-java-3.1.14-bin.jar",
>        identifier.quote="`")
> conn <- dbConnect(drv, "jdbc:mysql://localhost/test", "user", "pwd")
> ```
>
> Loads a JDBC driver for MySQL (adjust the path to the driver's JAR file as necessary) and connects to the local database "test". The connection handle conn is used for all subsequent operations.

For SQL Server, your code will look something like the following (from https://www.r-bloggers.com/connecting-to-sql-server-from-r-using-rjdbc/):

> ```
> require(RJDBC)
> drv <- JDBC("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver",
>             "C:/jdbc/mssql-jdbc-7.0.0.jre8.jar") 
> conn <- dbConnect(drv, "jdbc:sqlserver://serverName", "userID", "password")
> ```

Comment: do I need to install something or download sqldbc4.jar is enough?

Comment: I edited my answer to reference your specific .jar file.

Comment: do I need to install something? Because it still doesn't work. Now, however, I get error because of bad user/password... and before it couldn't find the server...

Comment: If you're able to find the server and get a user/password error, then you shouldn't need to install anything. At this point, you may want to create a new question.